# Поиск по двумерному массиву

Tags: php, массивы, поиск

Привет, есть двумерный массив php:

```
$urls = array(
  array('id'=>1,'url'=>'http://test.ru','code'=>'a','c'=>''),
  array('id'=>2,'url'=>'http://test2.ru','code'=>'b','c'=>''),
...
  array('id'=>20000,'url'=>'http://test20000.ru','code'=>'azazaza','c'=>''),
);
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы я указывал например код **b** из этого массива и у меня выводился url `http://test2.ru` из этого массива соответствующий запрошенному коду. всего таких элементов около 20К

Answer (score 1):

```
function getUrl($code){
    foreach($urls as $k=>$v){
        if ($v['code'] == $code)
            return $v['url'];
    }
}
```

Что то типа этого?

Answer (score 0):

Задавайте код как индекс массива, тогда все будет работать намного быстрее.

И функция будет выглядеть так:

```
function getUrl($code){
    if (isset($urls[$code])) {
        return $url[$code]['url'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Согласен - в PHP очень важно правильно планировать ключи. Тогда код будет гораздо более читаем, плюсую. Только пример можно было бы покрасивше оформить: `return isset($urls[$code]) ? $url[$code]['url'] : false;`

Comment: Вот и нет. В некоторых версиях php 5.x тернарный оператор вызывает потерю производительности.

Comment: это же обычный синтаксис, как оно прекомпилится - одному PHP известно, и явно не забота программиста. И читаемость + простота кода всегда превыше производительности: сервер стоит 10к.р./мес, а программист 100к/мес.. Наверное это религиозный вопрос в программировании, ответ ваш, как знаете :)

Comment: Вот и не стоит спорить

Answer (score 0):

```
$pos = array_values(array_filter($urls,function($a){
  return $a["code"] == 'b';
}));

print_r($pos[0]['url']);
```

Пару строчек и не каких циклов